# Why use Singletons?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oop, class, singleton

OK, I know this question might seem irrelevant or too basic, but - since I always want to know what I'm doing and why I'm doing it, if it fits my design - please shed some light.

So, here's what I need :

- Let's say we've got a class
- We want to use its methods from pretty much anywhere
- Instead of passing an object around, I decided to go for class methods and pseudo-global instances

So, let's say we've got a class named "MyDocumentManager".

---

**This is what I usually do :**

```
+ (MyDocumentManager*)documentManager
{
     MyDocumentManager* newDocumentManager = [[MyDocumentManager alloc] init];

     if (newDocumentManager)
     {
          // initialize that new document manager
     }
     return newDocumentManager;
}
```

**And then use it like :**

```
[[MyDocumentManager documentManager] someMethod];
```

---

However, I usually see people suggesting something like :

```
+ (MyDocumentManager*)sharedManager
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static MyDocumentManager *sharedManager;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedManager = [[MyDocumentManager alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedManager;
}
```

---

**So, here's my questions :**

- Is is the same thing?
- If not, what is the difference?
- What are the pros/cons of its approach? (in terms of memory/speed/etc)
- Which one should I use and why?
- Do they both fit what I need them for?

Comment: @pst You've got some point; however, my question title still seems fit to me : the question is not only about implementation but also about the very nature/use of singletons.

Comment: Those are two questions - and the latter is very well discussed on SO already. P.S. I think you missed a `static` in the first example.

Comment: @pst You mean in *my* code? I didn't miss anything. (And I didn't mention it was a singleton - just added the code I'm usually using... It turns out it's wrong...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it the same thing?

No.

> If not, what is the difference?

What you have doesn't implement a singleton, since it allocates a new instance of the class upon every function call. It's rather called a **factory method.** The definition of a singleton is that a certain class method always returns the same instance of the class.

> Which one should I use and why?

You should generally avoid using singletons, because it's often considered bad practice, although there are cases when it's handy to have them. For example, if you have a class that uses encapsulated data but you only need quasi class-level methods, then it's better to implement a singleton with properly placed instance variables than implement class methods and tons of global/static variables (this is because in Objective-C, classes can't have member variables, only objects).

> Do they both fit what I need them for?

You decide that.

Comment: OK, let's take this scenario as an example : I need several *globally-accessible* methods acting on some data (some initialization must be done, before the methods are used - but the actual "core" is immutable during runtime). What would *you* suggest? Is singletons such a bad idea?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Is the "some data" one specific piece of data? If so, a singleton may be a good choice. If not (i. e. you can have multiple of them), then he factory method you implemented would be a better fit.

Comment: Let me be more specific (it's still an example) : we have a dedicated class to process application settings. When the app launches, the settings are loaded. Each time I want to update/set/remove some option from the settings I'm using methods of the Settings class (to store/retrieve data to/from disk). What about this case?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon A singleton is usable in this case, but I suspect you can still avoid it... Is the class something like `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: I told you - I'm just trying to give you an example. I'm using this same pattern in a wide variety of cases (in which I would actually prefer something more old-style global-variable thing - I know, not the best thing, but that's what it feels like... lol). To be honest, if I wasn't trying to be ObjC-friendly, I could easily think of most of them as global C functions.

Comment: Btw, one of the reasons I'm trying to take a different approach (re: singletons) is because - after some profiling - I've noticed that my app takes up far more memory than I'd want it to... So, I'm optimization (though I bet there's still much room ahead for that...).

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Well, you can use a singleton, but I feel you're overengineering this a bit :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, mate! ;-) (I suppose I'll have to study a bit and revise my approach on that matter...)

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted in "what I usually do" is broken. It doesn't return a singleton. It returns a brand new object every time you call it (and if this isn't ARC then it's leaking it too).

The code you pasted as what people suggest is the correct code. Not only does it return a shared object each time, without leaking, but it's also thread-safe (so far as initialization of the object is concerned; it doesn't say anything about whether use of the object is thread-safe).

Comment: I didn't say it *is* a singleton. I just stated what I'm usually doing. (And yep, it **is** ARC-enabled).

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: The naming `+[MyDocumentManager documentManager]` conventionally means it returns a singleton. In fact, your "usual" method is nearly identical to just calling `+new` except for the fact that you have initialization code that you, for whatever reason, chose to not put in `-init`.